# XenServer 7 - Duplicate the USB stick?

Tags: xenserver, usb, clone

I have installed XenServer 7 on an usb stick like it's quite common with Esxi. I used my 64Gb stick thinking it will only use the required space and that I will be able to duplicate it later on a smaller key (with CloneZilla).

Problem, it has spawn is partition over all the space of the stick so now, Clonezilla can't clone it on a smaller key..

How can I do to reduce the space used by XenServer on the key, the key is probably 90% empty.. Or maybe there is another way to export xen server to the new usb stick ?

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Many ways**

**1.** You could mount it and copy the data to a new prepared (partitioned, formatted) USB stick, then reinstall the boot loader. I don't know much about XenServer specifically, but people do this with Linux all the time.

**2.** Here, one answer claims that Clonezilla can do it as long as the larger source disk is not full. There's lots of other ideas there too.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/409204/how-to-clone-to-a-smaller-harddisk

> Basically you need to enable the advanced options and "ignore" the warning message about a smaller disk.

**3.** It looks like Mondo Rescue does it too:
http://www.mondorescue.org/

Comment: You probably aimed me in the right direction but while looking at the GParted solution, I realised that the minimal space for XenServer 7 is now 48Gb, so going from a 64 gb stick to a 32 gb is not possible anyway.